# Determine when mouse stops moving

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to be able to tell when the user has stopped moving the mouse. I currently have the following in a picturebox mousemove event:

```
If e.Location.X < oldX Then
    mDir = "L"
ElseIf e.Location.X > oldX Then
    mDir = "R"
End If

ts1.Text = mDir
oldX = e.Location.X
```

However, this won't update the text box when the mouse stops moving until the user clicks or moves on the Y axis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `Application.Idle` event. In you `MouseMove` handler save `DateTime.Now` and in `Idle` handler when `(DateTime.Now - _lastAction)` is greater than a threshold then you detected a stop. You may even start/reset a timer for each move (and then when its event fires you'll detect a stop) but probably it's just a waste of resources.

Comment: Where is you code for the Y? These are for the X only. Do the same for Y.

Comment: I'm only using the X axis in this case Steve - hence the absence of the Y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Application.Idle` event, in your `MouseMove` handler you save time of last mouse action:

```
Private Sub Control_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) 
    ' Your code here...
    ' Save time of last mouse event
    _lastAction = DateTime.Now
End Sub
```

On `Idle` event handler you'll compare time of last action with actual time, if it's greater than an arbitrary threshold then you detected a stop:

```
Private Sub Application_Idle(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
    If DateTime.Now - _lastAction > TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100) Then
        mDir = "-"
    End If
End Sub
```

It's not your case (because, usually, you don't have such strict requirement for user's input timing) but a more precise solution should involve a `Timer`. You set its `Interval` to your threshold and you start (or reset) it at each mouse action. When user doesn't move mouse for that time then its `Tick` event will be fired: you pause timer and you detected the mouse stop. This is little bit more accurate than `Idle` processing but probably it's useless (and you just waste system resources) so I wouldn't prefer that over first solution.